# div with table display: alignment issue

Tags: html, css, web

I have the following code:

```css
div {
       box-sizing: border-box;
       border-style: solid;
}
div.table {
       display: table;
}
div.row {
       display: table-row;
}
div.cell {
       display: table-cell;
}
div.logo {
       width: 200px;
       height: 200px;
       border-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
    <div class="row">
       <div class="cell">
           <div class="logo"></div>
       </div>
       <div class="cell">
           Content
       </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The content of the second cell is aligned to the bottom of the div in the first one and appears at the very bottom of it's cell. When both cells are filled with text then content in both floats at the top.

**How can I get the content of the second cell to be positioned at the top of it's cell?**

The question must be silly, but I'm an absolute beginner in css and just don't know how to approach the issue.

Answer (score 4):

Use `vertical-align:top` to align table cells vertically.
`div`s normally have `vertical-align:baseline` in their default stylesheet definitions, which explains the display you see. Note that actual table cells (`td` and `th` elements) have `vertical-align:middle` by default.

```css
div {
       box-sizing: border-box;
       border-style: solid;
}
div.table {
       display: table;
}
div.row {
       display: table-row;
}
div.cell {
       display: table-cell;
       vertical-align:top;
}
div.logo {
       width: 200px;
       height: 200px;
       border-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
    <div class="row">
       <div class="cell">
           <div class="logo"></div>
       </div>
       <div class="cell">
           Content
       </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

do you mean this?
added `vertical-align:top` to `div.cell`

```css
div {
       box-sizing: border-box;
       border-style: solid;
}
div.table {
       display: table;
}
div.row {
       display: table-row;
}
div.cell {
       display: table-cell;
       vertical-align:top;
}
div.logo {
       width: 200px;
       height: 200px;
       border-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
    <div class="row">
       <div class="cell">
           <div class="logo"></div>
       </div>
       <div class="cell">
           Content
       </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Add `vertical-align` Attribute

```css
div {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-style: solid;
}
div.table {
  display: table;
}
div.row {
  display: table-row;
}
div.cell {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: top;
}
div.logo {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell">
      <div class="logo"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="cell">
      Content
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `vertical-align: top` in your css.

```
div.cell {
   display: table-cell;
   vertical-align: top;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Following should just work fine:

```css
div {
       box-sizing: border-box;
       border-style: solid;
}
div.table {
       display: inline-block;  /*changed this line*/
}
div.row {
       display: flex;          /*changed this line*/
}
div.cell {
       /* removed styles */
}
div.logo {
       width: 200px;
       height: 200px;
       border-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
    <div class="row">
       <div class="cell">
           <div class="logo"></div>
       </div>
       <div class="cell">
           Content
       </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Uhm I guess you're right. The table styles aren't needed anyway. You can just remove them and than use `display: inline-block` on `div.table`